# How to start and stop the Windows Oracle service using a Jenkins job?

Tags: java, ruby, windows, jenkins, oracle11g

I am using Oracle 11g. On a remote server (Windows server-12) I have three separate Oracle instances (SID).

I want to stop and start their Oracle services from Jenkins.

How can I do this with Jenkins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows service can be started and stopped using the command line:

```
net startservice
net stopservice
```

(See [the details](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc736564(v=ws.10).aspx) for "Start, stop, pause, resume, or restart a service").

Calling a shell command from Jenkins is quite easy with the build step "Execute command". Just be careful that Windows is bad/non predictive about when the service is effectively stopped. You may want to play around with some "waiting" clause, especially if you want to stop the start again.